# sonarqube 6.0 and motion chart plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Since I updated sonarqube to version 6.0, I can't get motionchart plugin to work ... All I get is a blank widget and a red top band with a [hide] button. Besides, I have found errors like this in the server log:

2016.08.26 14:23:19 ERROR web[rails] undefined method `snapshot' for #MeasureFilter::Row:0x641ff8d3

Has someone got the motion chart plugin 1.7 to work with sonarqube version 6.0?

Answer (score 3):

Motion Chart Plugin 1.7 is not compatible with SonarQube 6.0. For the time being, there's no plan to make it compatible.

Edit:

Nevertheless, I think that 2 new core features may help you manage your team on a day to day basis:

- [the Leak Period](http://www.sonarqube.org/water-leak-changes-the-game-for-technical-debt-management/)
- [the new Quality Model](http://www.sonarqube.org/bugs-and-vulnerabilities-are-1st-class-citizens-in-sonarqube-quality-model-along-with-code-smells/)

This features are central in the way we use our software everyday.

Comment: humm, it's a pity!

Comment: can you tell what is you use of the plugin?

Comment: With it I can easily see the efforts of the team to improve quality metrics (coverage, complexity, size and comments) over time ...

Comment: It also lets me identify risky packages and classes (the ones having a metric deviated from the average)